# How to select Specific known values in Multiple items in Pivot table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want select only specific set of values in the pivot table

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Opened by").CurrentPage = _
        "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Opened by")
        .PivotItems("") = False
        .PivotItems("Abilash").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("Adrien").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("AJAY").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("Akanksha").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("Akash").Visible = False
```

Kindly give me entire code to select the field, table and get it done right front.

I find it really difficult to find the right code to get the simple thing done. I find vb difficult on this front.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

The following macro first clears the filters, then it loops through each pivot item in the page field, and then sets the visible property to False for any pivot item which is included in `vPivotItemsToExclude`.

Note that I assumed that you meant "(blank)", not "".  If this is not the case, simply replace "(blank)" with "".

```
Dim vPivotItemsToExclude As Variant
vPivotItemsToExclude = Array("(blank)", "Akash") 'change and/or add as desired

Dim oPivotItem As PivotItem
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable")
    .ManualUpdate = True
    With .PivotFields("Opened by")
        .ClearAllFilters
        For Each oPivotItem In .PivotItems
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(oPivotItem.Caption, vPivotItemsToExclude, 0)) Then
                oPivotItem.Visible = False
            End If
        Next oPivotItem
    End With
    .ManualUpdate = False
End With
```